# Are eigenspaces in a Hilbert space rays?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, projective-space

It may sound as a dumb question but I just want to be sure that I understand all the terminology:

The eigenspaces corresponding to a (non-degenerate) eigenvalue of a operator on a Hilbert space are one-dimensional subspaces. Are they therefore elements of the projective Hilbert space, i.e. rays?

Thank you.

Comment: They are indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the elements of a projective Hilbert space are precisely the one-dimensional subspaces of a linear Hilbert space. The term   *ray* appears to be common in the projective space literature, though some people might associate this word with *half-line* in a real space. Calling them *lines* or *complex lines* would be better, in my opinion.